# Interstitial and vacancy defects

Tags: vasp, atomic-simulation-environment, pymatgen, defects

I'm trying to insert interstitial defects in an FCC crystal with 32 atoms. And also a quick way of inserting a vacancy or doing a substitutional defect. Any code for this would be deeply appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can use ASE to build *any* structure. The real question is how automated do you want it to be

Comment: @ShaunHan Any sample code to insert an oxygen atom into FCC tetrahedral or octahedral site would be deeply appreciated.